# Spring boot user registration - getting validation errors to the UI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am learning Springboot and trying to follow how the registration errors get to the UI in this Baeldung example [Registration Process](https://www.baeldung.com/registration-with-spring-mvc-and-spring-security) get to the UI. However the implementation on the Baeldung website is different to the linked Baeldung Github Project.

On the example in the webpage they have a registration controller that looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView registerUserAccount
  (@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid UserDto accountDto, 
  BindingResult result, WebRequest request, Errors errors) {    
     User registered = new User();
     if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        registered = createUserAccount(accountDto, result);
      }
     if (registered == null) {
        result.rejectValue("email", "message.regError");
     }
   // rest of the implementation
}

private User createUserAccount(UserDto accountDto, BindingResult result) {
  User registered = null;
  try {
      registered = service.registerNewUserAccount(accountDto);
  } catch (EmailExistsException e) {
      return null;
  }    
  return registered;
}
```

With corresponding HTML of :

```
<div>
    <label th:text="#{label.user.email}">email</label>
    <input type="email" th:field="*{email}"/>
    <p th:each="error : ${#fields.errors('email')}" h:text="${error}">Validation error</p>
</div>
```

I understand that the createUserAccount method can throw and error with exception which ultimately gets added to result object which boils through to the HTML via thymeleaf.

However in the linked [github](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration) project on the same web page the implementation is very different and I don't follow how the errors make there way to the UI.

The [controller](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/org/baeldung/web/controller/RegistrationController.java#L76) now looks like:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public GenericResponse registerUserAccount(@Valid final UserDto accountDto, final HttpServletRequest request) {
    LOGGER.debug("Registering user account with information: {}", accountDto);
    final User registered = userService.registerNewUserAccount(accountDto);
    eventPublisher.publishEvent(new OnRegistrationCompleteEvent(registered, request.getLocale(), getAppUrl(request)));
    return new GenericResponse("success");
    }
```

This calls [registerNewUserAccount](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/org/baeldung/service/UserService.java#L62) method which looks like:

```
    @Override
    public User registerNewUserAccount(final UserDto accountDto) {
    if (emailExist(accountDto.getEmail())) {
        throw new UserAlreadyExistException("There is an account with that email adress: " + accountDto.getEmail());
    }
    // rest of method
```

The [UserAlreadyExistException](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/org/baeldung/web/error/UserAlreadyExistException.java) class looks like :

```
public final class UserAlreadyExistException extends RuntimeException {

    public UserAlreadyExistException() {
        super();
    }

    public UserAlreadyExistException(final String message, final Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public UserAlreadyExistException(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public UserAlreadyExistException(final Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

Even the [registration HTML](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/registration.html) now is different, and appears not to use Thymeleaf for errors:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3" th:text="#{label.user.email}">email</label>
    <span class="col-sm-5"><input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="" required="required"/></span>                    
    <span id="emailError" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-4" style="display:none"></span>
</div>
```

> This all builds up to the question : how does this exception and the
>   associated messages bubble up back to the UI? In the implementation on the original example there were various errors (for example @NotEmtpty) that would be presented in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are confusing is: how does the error message pass to front page, as since in the controller there is no codes for it. Is my understanding correct?

Short answer:

It is done in global exception handler located at: https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/org/baeldung/web/error/RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java

More Details:

Commonly for spring controllers, we will use global exception handler to catch all the exceptions that is throw out from the controller methods, the exception itself can be from services code though. The handler method is annotated with `@ExceptionHandler`.

So the flow for the error message for "user already exists" case is like:

1. front end javascript do all the local verification like email format, password length, etc. Only when all those validation pass, it calls the api to register new user.
2. controller receives the request to register user.
3. controller calls service method to register new user.
4. service methods throws the already existed exception when detected.
5. controller did not catch the exception, so it gets throw out of the controller method.
6. global controller exception handler caught this exception and generate error response dto, populate error messages which is provided by message.properties for corresponding locale to the error response. The properties are located in src/main/resources and the file name declares the locale. After error response populated, it return it so spring will response this object to front end.
7. front end receives the response. The javascript check if it is an error. And if yes, it check what kind of error it is then handle correspondingly.

This kind of flow may not be very intuitively at first. But once you understand it you shall be happy using it. It can save a lot of codes for handling errors in the controller.

I think the controllerAdvice is implemented using AOP, which is a very powerful tool. If you want to know more you can further research yourself.

Regarding the validation error handling:

The exception handler inherits [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html), which handles the validation result from the validation of the request payload. See the first two override method of the handler. This is new to me as well, good to know!

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I have looked at the code since and see they have moved almost entirely away from using Thymeleaf. This is what is confusing me. I wonder if there is a way to use the "result" object with the error message.

Comment: @AlGrant The binding result in the controller parameter list is the "validation" result that comes from your user dto's validation. If you want to forward the error that generated from this validation result, you can create the error response and directly set error message to it then return the response back. So in front-end it will display the validation error. I updated the answer a bit to include the details for binding result handling in the repository.